# How do I determine whether an IEnumerable of roles contains any roles from string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a string array which contains multiple role ID's.  In my controller I want to return a list of Users who have one or more of the roles found in the array for the purposes of sending an email.  So something like:

```
var sendto = db.Users
            .Where(j => j.Roles.SelectMany(h => h.RoleId).Any(model.SelectedRoles))
            .ToList();
```

Where model.SelectedRoles is the string array of role ID's and j.Roles is the Roles table for MVC identity, which contains the string field Role ID which I am matching to any of the entries in the string array.

Obviously the query above does not work and is incorrect.  I've just put something in there to sort of show what I would like to do.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the intersect method can help you:

```
var sendto = db.Users
            .Where(j => j.Roles.Select(h => h.RoleId).Intersect(model.SelectedRoles).Any())
            .ToList(); // Note that in your answer it was SelectMany
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look at the intersect method, however the query you have written errors with intellisense "IEnumerable<char> does not contain a definition for intersect"

Comment: @Rob First - are Roles an enumerable of string? if so just replace SelectMany with Select. I added an option in my answer. Second - of course IEnumerable<char> contains a definition for intersect! Are you missing using System.Linq?

Comment: RoleID is a string in MVC identity, I changed your query from SelectMany to Select and it worked.  Will mark as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Any()`:

```
var sendto = db.Users
    .Where(j => j.Roles
        .Any(h => model.SelectedRoles.Any(i => i == h))
    )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return a list of Users who have one or more of the roles found in the array

***one or more of the roles*** translates to `Any`, and ***found in the array*** translates to `Contains`:

```
var sendto = db.Users
    .Where(user => user.Roles.Any(role => model.SelectedRoles.Contains(role.RoleId)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `SelectedRoles` is a Role[ ], you cannot supply `RoleId`, it needs Role object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj From OP explanation: *Where model.SelectedRoles is the **string array** of role ID's*

Comment: Ok thanks, strangely enough even `Id` would be `string` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var sendto = db.Users
            .Where(j => model.SelectedRoles.Contains(j.Roles))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but intellisense does not like your query, "model.SelectedRoles does not contain a definition for 'Contains'"

Comment: What is the type of SelectedRoles property?

Comment: If model.SelectedRoles is string array, it must have Contains

Comment: model.SelectedRoles is a string array, as specified in the question.  With a small modification the other answer worked, thanks anyway.

Comment: If a User object contains multiple `Roles`, then this would not work without flattening the User list